# Charts.js : How to remove the Vertical Black lines in Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

How can I remove the vertical black lines, which are getting displayed both sides of bars in the bar chart?

I tried both

```
 options : {
scaleShowVerticalLines: false
}

options : {
    scales : {
        xAxes : [ {
            gridLines : {
                display : false
            }
        } ]
    }
}
```

here is my code lines:

```
//Chart Axis's


let scales = {
    xAxes: [{
        gridLines: { display: false },
        ticks: {
            font: {
                size: config.size,
            },
            color: "white",
        },
      
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero:true
        },
    }]
};



 let ctx = document.getElementById('how_i_spend_canvas');
        if (ctx) { // DOM element is present and not null
            let categoriesChart = new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d'), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: howISpendChartdata,
                // Chart pulgins & Options
                plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
                options: {
                    scales: scales,
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    aspectRatio: 2,
                    plugins: plugins,
                   }
}
                onClick: function (evt, element) {}
```

****but iy didn't work for me*.***

Reference where the arrow is pointing the lines.

[image: Screen shot of the chart]

Comment: Can you post your full code ? It should work, please check following jsfiddle >> 
https://jsfiddle.net/1wjh8b5n/

Comment: @Rukshán this is my code  //Chart Axis's
    let scales = {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: { display: false },
            ticks: {
                font: {
                    size: config.size,
                },
                color: "white",
            },
          
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            },
        }]
    };

Comment: let ctx = document.getElementById('how_i_spend_canvas');
    if (ctx) { // DOM element is present and not null
        let categoriesChart = new Chart(ctx.getContext('2d'), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: howISpendChartdata,
            // Chart pulgins & Options
            plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
            options: {
                scales: scales,
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                aspectRatio: 2,
                plugins: plugins,
               
                onClick: function (evt, element) {

Comment: If you are using V3 don't tag your question with a tag that says you are using v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer now as in Chart JS 3 they have changed to **grid** instead of the common **gridlines** command.

Now in chart JS 3 can use :

```
x: {
     grid:{
           color:'red',
           display: false,
        }
  },
  

  y:{
      ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true
    },

  grid: {
        color: 'green',
        display: true,
    }
  }
```

[Result ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO3Pt.png)